# changing permissions of files in a directory recursively

Tags: linux, find, chmod

I am trying to change the permissions of a files present in a directory and subdirectories using the below command and running into below error..can anyone help?

```
user@machine:/local/mnt/workspace$ find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod: changing permissions of `./halimpl/ncihal/adaptation/NonVolatileStore.cpp': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 11):

you can run the following command:

```
 #chown -R directory_path
```

But it will change the permissions of directories also.

For only files, you can run.

```
 #find directory_path -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

It also looks like you dont have enough permissions. try

```
 #sudo find directory_path -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

or run the command as root user.

Comment: Here something like that as Script:

https://github.com/ieselisra/wordpress_fix_permissions_debian10

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you don't have permission to change NonVolatileStore.cpp.

Are you aware of `chmod`'s `-R` switch that recursively changes permissions?

Comment: `chmod -R` would set permissions on directories too, which is probably not what's wanted.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  That's why I didn't suggest that he merely `chmod -R` everything.  It's still possible, however, that he's unaware of `chmod -R`.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the root privilege, try:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you simply don't own that file. Run an `ls -l` on it to see full permissions and who the owner is.

It could also be the filesystem is read only.