# Error in Module Loader

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am very new in `SugarCRM`. I created a module from:

```
ADMIN -> Developer Tools -> module builder
```

And created a package, auto downloaded the zip which contains `manifiest.php` and went to module loader and uploaded this and while installing it which through following:

```
Progress = 29% STOP!!!

click in link "Display Log"

**Message:** Installing Images

Warning: dir(cache/upgrades/temp/191D.tmp/icons) [function.dir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Sugar\include\dir_inc.php on line 52
Failed to copy cache/upgrades/temp/191D.tmp/icons custom/themes
```

How can I fix this error?

**manifest.php**

```
<?php

$manifest = array (
    0 => 
        array (
            'acceptable_sugar_versions' => 
                array (
                    0 => '',
                ),
            ),    
    1 => 
        array (
            'acceptable_sugar_flavors' => 
                array (
                    0 => 'CE',
                    1 => 'PRO',
                    2 => 'ENT',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    'readme' => '',
    'key' => 'sharm',
    'author' => 'Admin',
    'description' => 'testing module for adding custom module',
    'icon' => '',
    'is_uninstallable' => true,
    'name' => 'sharma',
    'published_date' => '2014-07-22 06:35:58',
    'type' => 'module',
    'version' => 1406010958,
    'remove_tables' => 'prompt',
);

$installdefs = array(
    'id' => 'sharma',
    'beans' => array (),
    'layoutdefs' => array (),
    'relationships' => array (),
    'image_dir' => '<basepath>/icons',
);
```

Comment: You need give proper permission for the folder like chmod -R 755 floder

Comment: to which folder? i should give permission

Comment: i tried as u said,but it remain same.stuck in 29%

Comment: try to give 755 permissions to custom/themes folder

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892593/changing-permissions-of-files-in-a-directory-recursively